# Where do I get open data on open source projects?

Tags: dataset, open-source

I'm trying to find out how many open source projects related to hydrological/environmental modelling are out there, and derive some basic information (e.g. total number, deployments per year, etc.).

Where can I get this info from?

(I have checked OpenHub, GitHub and SourceForge but it seems I cannot download the list of project and related information.)

Comment: I disagree with the decision of putting this post off-topic. Quoting the Help Center > Asking:What topics can I ask about here? *collecting data* is one of the options.

Comment: Lilith, let me clarify. While "collecting data" is indeed a valid topic on CrossValidated site, it makes more sense to have here data collection questions, focused on statistical perspective of data collection. Open Data StackExchange site, on the other hand, is much better suited for questions on open data sets, so I agree with moderators' suggestion. Unless you have a specific reason to avoid that site, if you'd register on Open Data SE (takes just a moment), this question could be migrated there by moderators and the off-topic flag would be cleared, if I understand correctly the procedure.

Comment: I'm now registered to OD SE and I don't mind if the moderator migrates my question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a warning from my experience: you will **not** be able to get *meaningful* data on open source projects' *deployments* on a large (geographical) scale. What you can do in that regard, though, is to use *number of downloads* a very approximate **proxy measure** for assessing the projects' *adoption*.

Having said that, I think that you can download some information of your interest from those three project *repositories* and *meta-repositories* that you have mentioned, but it's not trivial. You have to use a particular set of **APIs** for each of them. *GitHub* data is most likely the easiest to access and their set of APIs is relatively simple. *OpenHub* (formerly *Ohloh*) left me with an extremely negative impression in terms of their feedback to researchers that wanted to use their "open" data (haven't used their data set). I've been able to use *SourceForge* data set for my dissertation research, but even that is available to researchers or students under an *academic license*. For that, you need to request credentials from a specific person at Notre Dame University, which manages the research-focused version of *SourceForge* data set, called *SourceForge Research Data Archive (SRDA)*.

As a subset of **software** for my dissertation's data analysis, I have written some open source `R` software that works with *SRDA* (and FLOSSmole meta-repository as well). However, currently the code is not in a form of a standard R package, for various reasons. You are welcome to take a look at it on the following GitHub page: https://github.com/abnova/diss-floss-official (it is not fully and properly documented yet as well). I plan to convert that software into two separate packages - for *multi-source open source data collection* and for *open source ecosystem analysis* - if / when I will have a chance. I also recommend you to include *CRAN* and *R-Forge* into your data sources, as `R` *ecosystem* contains an impressive number of open source software packages in multitude of *scientific domains* and I would be very surprised, if *hydrology* is an exclusion from that tradition.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Aleksandr! I'm trying to generate a comprehensive review of projects and, at least for the time being I won't focus on one particular programming language. However, that is definitely something to take into account in the future.

Comment: @Lilith: You're very welcome! Feel free to upvote/accept my answer, if it is helpful / you're satisfied. I very much agree with your language-agnostic approach, as I like comprehensive reviews as well. One more thought - it might be easier and more time-efficient to just manually collect data (not scrape!) than to learn several sets of APIs, as I don't expect the number of projects in hydrology to be too high.